# How to create a Custom Authorize Attribute by comparing User Id stored in table with Current User Id in Asp.net MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, authorize-attribute

I need to control access to edit method of my controller on the basis of user id i.e only that user can access the edit method who created that specific data.
User Id is stored in the table EmpProfile UserID column and want to compare the current logged in user with the UserID stored and allow access on this basis. 
My Custom Authorize Attribute Code is:

```
public class AuthorizeAuthorAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{        
    RecruitDB mydb = new RecruitDB();   // My Entity
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!isAuthorized)
        {
            return false;
        }
        string CurrentUser = httpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString(); // Current User ID(Converted to string)

        var userName = from m in mydb.EmpProfiles            //Calling method to get UserID from EmpProfile.UserID Column
                       where m.UserID == CurrentUser
                       select m.UserID;
        string my = userName.ToString();                    //Converting to string
        if (CurrentUser.Contains(my))                       //Comparing
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }       
}
```

Controller Code:

```
[AuthorizeAuthor]
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
    }
```

But by applying the Authorization i am always directed to login page.
Also when the user is same as author.

Comment: I don't think logic in Attributes should be "heavy" (e.g. by doing database hits). The original Authorize attribute only compared data in the user's auth cookie, which is fast in-memory logic. By hiding expensive code in an attribute you hide the complexity of your application's logic to other developers.

Comment: By adding [Authorize(User="SomeUser")] to my action only permits specific hard coded user to enter. But how can a user how created the data can only be Authorized. For it Current User ID and data creator user id should match.Much Like Sites User Dashboard can only be accessed by the user creating it. Does MVC provide such Authorization? Please Advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your comment:

> By adding `[Authorize(User="SomeUser")]` to my action only permits specific hard coded user to enter. But how can a user how created the data can only be Authorized. For it Current User ID and data creator user id should match.Much Like Sites User Dashboard can only be accessed by the user creating it. Does MVC provide such Authorization? Please Advice

You are correct in noting that the `Authorize` attribute, like all attributes in .NET, can only have const arguments.

For flexibility you cannot use an attribute in this circumstance, you must implement your own authorization logic and perform the call from your controller action, like so:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Int32? id) {
    // Repeat the below logic for each action you want access-control in, ensure it is also in your POST handlers too.
    if( !this.IsAuthorized() ) return this.Http401();
}

protected boolean IsAuthorized() {
    if( this.Request.User.Identity.Name == "someoneIDontLike" ) return false;
    return true;
}

protected ActionResult Http401(String message) {
    this.Response.StatusCode = 401;
    // This requires you to create your own custom HTTP 401 "Unauthorized" view file and viewmodel
    return this.View( new Http401ViewModel(message) );
}
```

Comment: I have stored UserID in EmpProfile table and retrieving it as userName Comparing with User.Identity.GetUserId() and passing it to if ( IsAuthorized(id) ) statement.Edit logic is inside If statement.But not working...